# HttpResponse StatusCode 410

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

In my Android App, I retrieve data from SQL Server through WebApi.

- API is working when I check it in the browser.
- SQL Server remote access is working and I have checked the connection through IP.
- Android App is working AVD.
- Android App is working in my physical mobile device when I connect my Mobile to the same network of the server.

**The problem is** 
when I run the App from a different network, the HttpResponse.getStatusLine().statusCode = 410.

previously everything was perfect. I just turned off the computer in the night and started in the morning and now this error.

I have tried the following:

- Disabled the firewall.
- Restarted the SQL Server and SQL Browser.
- Restarted the API in IIS.
- Restarted the Modem.
- Checked the Port for API which is open.
- Port 1433 is open.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does 410 mean?

Comment: Which url or ip do you use when not in the same network?

Comment: My public static IP with the port number e.g. 182.xxx.xx.xxx:port number/API/controller/querystring

Comment: a 410 error means “gone.” In Google's terms, “the server returns this response when the requested resource has been permanently removed. It is similar to a 404 (Not found) code but is sometimes used in the place of a 404 for resources that used to exist but no longer do.

Comment: And did you forward that port on your router?

Comment: yes, of course.